# Where can I get Koiwai coffee milk delivered to Europe?

Tags: milk

Since I went to Japan on holidays I've been craving the coffee milk that I've had over there, but I haven't been able to get it at home.

[image]

No local asian stores stock it and I haven't been able to find any online stores (although admittedly I have been looking at only English-speaking sites) that have any available - or deliver to Europe.

I'm not sure what it is about it, but i've been thinking about it ever since. **Is there somewhere online where I can order some?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can buy them from [Rakuten](http://global.rakuten.com/en/store/yamakuya/item/kirin-koiwai-miruku-to-coffee/). They ship internationally, with the exception of some countries, due to them not sufficing to the standards.

I don't believe there to be such a limit in Europe though, so you should be fine.

It costs ¥ 3,369 which comes down to roughly $27. And no account is required to order.

Comment: ah, I was looking on them earlier and only saw cans. thanks!

Comment: Note that international shipping will be extra (and can vary depending on weight) and will probably be subjected to taxes and other restrictions upon entry in customs.

Comment: unfortunately, where I am (ireland) is one of those restrictions, but theoretically I can use a forwarding company, although for more €€€